# PHP replace string inside special characters

Tags: php, replace, expression

I know it's easy for the most of the people, but it isn't for me, regular expressions pain me alot.

What I need is to replace all the string inside the '%s' ... '%s' for a  element:

original:  I have read and accept %sthe terms of booking%s

what i want is to replace all the '%sthe terms of booking%s' for something like:

```
<a href="..." id="enlaceCondiciones" target="_blank" >Condiciones de venta</a>
```

Thanks in advance.

PD: Text inside the '%s' - '%s' changes depending on the user language, so a simple str_replace is not a solution in this case

Comment: `str_replace` is quite enough for the task as given.

Comment: no its not, because the text inside the '%s' are not always the same, it changes depending on the language that the user uses

Comment: 'the task as given' is key here. If you have multiple expression (and/or don't know all of them), use `preg_replace('/%s[^%]+%s/', 'string_to_replace', $your_string)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$output = preg_replace("/%s(.+)%s/", "<a href="..." id="enlaceCondiciones" target="_blank" >$1</a>", '%sthe terms of booking%s');
```

$output:

```
<a href="..." id="enlaceCondiciones" target="_blank" >the terms of booking</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're hacking together a basic templating system and want to replace all of the `%s...%s` tags in a string without necessarily knowing which are present. You'd need to do this in 3 steps.

1. Find all the tags:

   ```
   preg_match_all('/(%s[^%]%s)/', $input, $matches);
   ```
2. Get your replacements. This is dependent on your code, but basically just loops through `$matches`.
3. Replace the tags, you can do this in one batch by loading your searches and replacements into arrays:

   ```
   str_replace(array('%sone%s','%stwo%s'), array('uno', 'dos'), $input);
   ```

As a note, you should always try to use the basic string functions when possible. Regular expressions incur overhead in processing and memory use that are unnecessary when doing simple operations.